# Jquery custom date validator works only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-validate, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I've faced an issue when tried to add custom validating method to jQuery.validator:

```
$.validator.addMethod("fromDate", function (value, element) {
    var fromDateTime = moment(value, 'm/dd/yyyy HH:mm');
    var toDateTime = moment($("#endDate").val(), 'm/dd/yyyy HH:mm');
    if (fromDateTime.isValid() && toDateTime.isValid()) {
        return toDateTime.diff(fromDateTime) > 0;
    }

    return false;
}, "Start datetime should be less than end datetime");

$('#queryingDateForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#queryingDateForm').validate({
        rules: {
            start: {
                required: true,
                fromDate: true
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            load();
        }
    });
});
```

This line of code works correctly only first time, so validation works only once.

```
return toDateTime.diff(fromDateTime) > 0;
```

Second time and so on it returns the value which was returned first time.

Html:

```
<form id="queryingDateForm">
    <div class="input-group input-daterange">
        <input class="form-control dateTimePicker" id="startDate" type="datetime" placeholder="Date Start" name="start" required  />
        <span class="input-group-addon">@QueryingResources.To</span>
        <input class="form-control dateTimePicker" id="endDate" type="datetime" placeholder="Date End" name="end" required />

        <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success searchQuery" id="searchDateBtn">@QueryingResources.Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and that is how the bootstrap datetimepicker is initialized:

```
$(".dateTimePicker").datetimepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    format: 'm/dd/yyyy hh:ii'
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The `.validate()` method is only use for initializing the plugin.**

With your version below, the form is already in the process of being submitted before the validation plugin has even been initialized.

```
$('#queryingDateForm').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#queryingDateForm').validate({ ....
```

- How can validation take place *after* the submit event has been started?
- How can validation take place without the plugin first being initialized?

You would never put the `.validate()` method inside of a `submit` event (or `click` event) handler.

---

The plugin already automatically captures the click and blocks the submit of the form.  It simply gets called on page load within the DOM ready event handler...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.validator.addMethod("fromDate", function (value, element) {
        // your function
        ....
    });

    $('#queryingDateForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        // your options
        ....
    });

});
```